# JasperReport stretch with overflow for chinese character on PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on jasper report to stretch text field dynamically with Chinese character but failed with multiple test cases. The PDF result looks great from local generated by iReport but failed on my testing JBoss server. I believe this issue is related to fonts and confirmed by reading [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/why-my-text-not-displayed-correctly-pdf) reference. Following are steps I setup my testing environment and test cases:

- Install fonts (Arial Unicode MS and Ming(ISO 10646)) into java;
- Confirm fonts installed correctly by printing out java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
- Create fonts extension with iReport 3.6.1 and add to class path

**testing.Jrxml**

```
<detail>
<band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="246" y="35" width="150" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS"/>
        </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["扭扭車，盒子 ，淨水器，膠水，汽車啟動應急電源，電池，麥克風asdfkljhqwerpouikljhsdfgklhn,mhjzkxlchuioe"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</band>
</detail>
```

**What I have tried**

- Add pdfFontName=Arial Unicode MS and set pdfEncoding=Identity-H
- Use fonts Ming(ISO 10646)
- Stretch text field filled with english(success)
- Add multiple "\n" in the middle of chinese characters(stretched successfully but difficult to control)

**Server environment**

Aix 7.1 with JasperReport 3.6.1

Any suggestions for further testing are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.